# Django return custom json and add values that need to be deal with

Tags: json, django, django-serializer

I get a json result, and the `images` part is not match with the id 
like:

```
{
    "id": 11 
    "title":"AAA"
    "createday":"2015-01-01"    
    "images": [
        "B_123.jpg"
    ],    
}, 
{
    "id": 12 
    "title":"BBB"
    "createday":"2015-01-01"    
    "images": [
        "A_123.jpg"
    ],    
},
```

But actually,id=11 should match the image `A_123.jpg` ,and id=12 should match the image `B_123.jpg`

Because the `images` need to do something in function,so they can't match very well.

How can I let it match with right order?

Here is my code:

views.py

```
item_list = CombineQueryset(queryset1, queryset2)
return Response(item_list.jsonlize(request))
```

serializes.py

```
class CombineQueryset(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, query1, query2, *args, **kwargs):
        def get_images(dictionary, obj):
            images = []
            for image in obj.image_set.all():
                images.append(image.path)
            dictionary["images"] = images
            return dictionary

        query_list1 = query1.values(
            'title',
            'createday',
            'id',
        )
        .....   
        query_list1 = map(get_images, query_list1, query1)
        self.query_list = query_list1 + query_list2
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume it must be due to something in code not shown, such as different ordering of `query_list1` vs `query1` or that `id=12` is in `query2` and the code for `query_list2` is not an exact cut and paste of the code for `query_list1`.

try this instead:

```
class CombineQueryset(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, query1, query2, *args, **kwargs):
        def querylist(queryset):
            return [
                {
                    'title': obj.title,
                    'createday': obj.createday,
                    'id': obj.id,
                    'images': obj.image_set.values_list('path', flat=True),
                }
                for obj in queryset
            ]

        self.query_list = querylist(query1) + querylist(query2)
```